# Dedicated web server, nodeJS can't run app

Tags: node.js, apache, server

Ok I have setup my own webserver on a pc running fedora server. Everything is configured properly. I have my dns server pointing my domain to the IP and can connect. The problem is that I want to run a node app on the server. I can't find the right guide or examples. What it seems, is that I have to run 'node app' on the server through terminal. Everytime I do, I get this error.

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 192.168.1.5:8080
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
at listen (net.js:1294:10)
at net.js:1404:9
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

From what I have read, it means the port isn't open.  Yet it is. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this. The same code changed to this pc works fine locally.

```
var http = require('http'),
express = require('express'),
app = express();

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, '192.168.1.5');

console.log('Server running at http://192.168.1.5:8080/');
```

Comment: Looks like you have multiple instances of the server running on the port `8080`

Comment: You may be running another node.js instance. Type this into a terminal: `killall node` and then try to start your app again.

Comment: sh: line 0: kill: all: arguments must be process or job IDs is what I got from that. Also I just restarted the pc and ran node app and still same error

Comment: You were correct, I couldn't get kill all to work, so I used htop and there were several instances running. It is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see what processes are using that port with

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

The last column is "PID/Program name" get the pid that's running on that port, then run

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```